# How to switch between internal and external builds on iTunes TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an iOS app in iTunesConnect. Let's say with v1 in external testing and v2 in internal testing, is there a way for a user with a single device to switch back and forth between testing the internal TestFlight build and the external TestFlight build?  Can it be done with mulitple Apple ID's, one for external and one for internal testing?  I've tried this, but with no luck so far.

Comment: So this is a single device, and you want to invite a single Apple ID to both Internal testing and External Testing in TestFlight? I don't think you can't invite a user for both Internal testing and External testing since when you add an internal tester email to external testing, it will be shown an error saying:  *"The email is already associated with an internal tester"*

Comment: I've also tried multiple Apple ID's.  One Apple ID for internal and a different one for external testing.  Still doesn't work, as it says I've already accepted the invitation for this app, or something like that.  I've also spoken with Apple Dev support who says it's not possible.  But I'm hoping someone has come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to switch an external tester to internal tester by having them select "Stop Testing" in the TestFlight app and then sending a new invite to test as an internal tester.  I would imagine this would work either way.

Comment: I think it's also probably possible to have the admin remove them rather that having to make the user tap the "Stop Testing" in the TestFlight app? Seems like a nice workaround, thanks!